# Hard drive not being recognised after booting into Windows?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I just got myself an internal Western Digital caviar black 1TB hard drive. I installed it without too much trouble. The SATA's are plugged correctly and the bios is recognizing it, but it doesn't show up in Windows 7.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting ideas or tips I can step through to try and make Windows see my new drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click My Computer and select Manage
2. Click on Disk Management

In the right hand window you should see all of your drives with their drive letter. Assuming you have one internal drive and one CD/DVD drive you should see

C: 
D:

If you see another drive listed but without a drive letter do the following:

Right click on it and you will see the menu
-new partition 
-properties 
-help

Create a partition on the new HDD and voila - It should now allocate it the next drive letter along in the sequence and it will show up in Windows.

HTH

Comment: Worked a treat.